# Injecting touch events in android OS witthout rooting

Tags: android, linux, root, android-permissions

I want to develop an app that injects touch events globally (not only in its context, but in any other app). I will do this by implementing the injection code in a service class that will be running in the background. After a long search I found that injecting touch events globally needs a rooted device or the app must be a system app, plus having INJECT_EVENTS permission defined in the manifest. My only concern is how to do this without rooting, because I don't want the app to affect the security of the device.

Compiling the app as a system app also has a problem. I don't want my app to be installed on my device only, but on any user's device. In this case how can I know the signature key of every device? Is there a way in which my app can be granted root privileges without rooting the device?

I found this app here that uses a server to inject events without rooting 
the device,

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vmlite.vncserver

Is there anything special about using a server? Can it grant touch injection permission?

Another way is to install your app in /system folder. But, that also needs rooting.

Please help, I want to have my app running without having to root the device, and I want anyone to be able to install it. How can I do that if I want it to be a system app? Or is there any other way to accomplish that?

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It is perfectly legit to inject events an Android system from app with INJECT_EVENTS permission without rooting a device. INJECT_EVENTS is however 'signature' level permission. It means that your app has to be signed by a vendor of the Android system respectively by a system certificate in order to do so.